# ConnectApi in a Community : EntityLink segment not allowed. Contact your administrator to enable it

Tags: community, chatter, notification

I'm using ConnectApi to send "bell notifications".

Example ( I use [ConnectApiHelper](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper) but my [pull request](https://github.com/forcedotcom/ConnectApiHelper/pull/15) allowing {record:xxx} is not validated yet ) :

```
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
messageInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = 'Have you seen this ';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput markupBeginSegment = new ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput();
markupBeginSegment.markupType = ConnectApi.MarkupType.Bold;
messageInput.messageSegments.add(markupBeginSegment);

textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = 'gorgeous';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput markupEndSegment = new ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput();
markupEndSegment.markupType = ConnectApi.MarkupType.Bold;
messageInput.messageSegments.add(markupEndSegment);

textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = ' view? ';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

ConnectApi.InlineImageSegmentInput inlineImageSegment = new ConnectApi.InlineImageSegmentInput();
inlineImageSegment.fileId = '069x00000000D7m';
inlineImageSegment.altText = 'View of the Space Needle from our office.';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(inlineImageSegment);

textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegment.text = ' \nBy the way, please check ';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(textSegment);

ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput entityLinkSegment = new ConnectApi.EntityLinkSegmentInput();
entityLinkSegment.entityId = '01t3E000002GCm9QAG';
messageInput.messageSegments.add(entityLinkSegment);

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
input.body = messageInput;
input.subjectId = 'me';

ConnectApi.FeedItem fi = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), input);
```

When this code is run from SFDC CRM, it works fine.

But when this code is run from a community, I see the following message in the debug logs :

**EntityLink segment not allowed. Contact your administrator to enable it**

I've looked everywhere in the setup and internet but I didn't find where to cenable EntityLink in chatter post in Communities.

Do anyone know where I could find such configuration ?

Comment: Did you get the answer for this issue?

Comment: I don't remember so, sorry :/